# Extensions in vs code

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, visual-studio-code

I have a question. I used vs code for python and I used some extensions for python like the python extension from microsoft. I currently want to use vs code for html,css and javascript. Does the pythons extensions affect my work in other languages and html and css? Do I need to disable them?

Comment: Those are automatically associated with the file type you are editing. So, when you are on a .html or .css file, vs code disables the tools and intellisense associated with python or any other coding feature non-related with your file.

Answer (score 4):

No. Extensions for languages are usually associated with a file type (`.py`, `.css`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If the extentions you want to install in vscode dont depened on each other they will have seperated inner routines and frameworks. So no "collisions" or anything like that. In case of python you can have different environments per projects which can be tricky to handle. To learn more about that have a look at pyvenv or virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

It will have no effect, you don't need to disable it, because the extension only runs if you use a file format with .py

Answer (score 0):

If your files are separated with their respective file type names attached (i.e. .css, .scss, .sass, .html, .py) the extensions designed for Python would theoretically only affect the Python files. If it's a really bad extension with low reviews maybe it would have a bug, but this is highly doubtful if you stick to highly-rated plugins. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

No, they will not anithing. Because they are build to execute just with python files then any file that doesn't have (.py) at the end it will not be affected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32625127)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).